# How to solve this array problems

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm learning arrays in my java programing class and I have been given a program that was pretty challenging for me. I have to write a program with an input files consisting of series of lines, with one word per line. I have to write a program that will tell the user if the word uses distinct letters (duplicated letters) or not.

Here is my input files:

```
UNCOPYRIGHTABLE
FLIPPER
EXECUTABLE
UNPROFITABLE
QUESTIONABLE
WINDOW
TAMBOURINE
```

This is what I have right now:

```
Scanner df = new Scanner (new Files (distinctlet.in"));

while (df.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = df.nextLine();
    String array [] = line.split("");

    String ans = "";

    for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
    {

        for (int m = k + 1; m < array.length; m++)
        {
            if (!array[k].equals(array[m])
            {
                ans = "USES DISTINCT LETTERS";
            }
            else
            {
                ans = "DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS";
            }

        }//FOR LOOP2

    }//FOR LOOP

    System.out.println(line + " " + ans);

}//WHILE DF
```

My output are supposed to be :

```
UNCOPYRIGHTABLE USES DISTINCT LETTERS
FLIPPER DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS
EXECUTABLE DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS
```

and so on...

my output right now is the word of the input and "DOES NOT USE DISTINCTIVE LETTERS" on every line. I know that the problems is within the nested loops but I dont't know how to fix this. thank you for the help.

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with the solution. For starter why `  String array [] = line.split("");`?

Comment: Before you tackle it in code, you should describe the solution in simple pseudocode.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao it splits the line into single characters. Sure, you could just use `toCharArray()` instead, and that would be a `char[]` rather than a `String[]`, but you end up with logically the same thing: an array of elements which contain a single character. That's hardly the most important issue here.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao sure about that? https://ideone.com/RfJMTZ

Comment: The algorithm needs a tweak; the current code returns the result of the very last comparison; instead start with the assumption that the word does use distinctive letters, then during the loop if you find a duplicate, you know it does not use distinctive letters.

Comment: @AndyTurner I stand corrected.

Comment: @haileysponses you probably need a `break` once you know the characters are matching.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I do when tackling a programming problem is diagramming/draw/write out <s>sudo</s> pseudo code and pictures. I ***always*** do this. It gets easier as you mature your programming skills.

With a problem like this, I would first think how to solve the *core* question.

Core question: Detect strings with duplicate chars.

With this in mind, my first idea is to just iterate through each string checking each position against the previous positions.

```java
String input = "inputString";
for(int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if(input[i].equalsIgnoreCase(input[j])){
            return false; //duplicate detected
        }
    }
}
return true; //No duplicates
```

This answer is very simple, and wouldn't work for larger size inputs(it would be far too slow!). With the core question answered, you just need to write the rest of the code!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To solve these kind of problems you can do like, this solution can solve very easily to your problem but here we are just taking a constant space which is 256 length array and `complexity will be O(n)`:

```
int []star = new int[256];
        while (df.hasNextLine())
        {
            Arrays.fill(star,0);
            String line = df.nextLine();
            for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++){
                star[line.charAt(0)]++;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
                if(star[i]>0 && star[i]>1){
                    System.out.println("Duplicate characters present..");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("No Duplicate characters present..");
            }
```

I hope you have got an idea..

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not use an array to do this - I would use a map. Even if you must use an array, I would still solve this in the spirit of a map.

Here the `counter` array is acting like a map (key=index, value=count).

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("data/input.csv"));
        String s = new String(encoded, Charset.defaultCharset());
        String[] split = s.split("\n");
        System.out.println("Input: " + Arrays.toString(split));
        System.out.println("Output: " + Arrays.toString(check(split)));
    }

    private static String[] check(String[] strings) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
            strings[i] += distinct(strings[i])
                    ? " USES DISTINCT LETTERS"
                    : " DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS";
        return strings;
    }

    private static boolean distinct(String string) {
        int[] counter = new int[string.length()];
        for (char c : string.toCharArray())
            if (++counter[string.indexOf(c)] > 1) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
Input: [UNCOPYRIGHTABLE, FLIPPER, EXECUTABLE, UNPROFITABLE, QUESTIONABLE, WINDOW, TAMBOURINE]
Output: [UNCOPYRIGHTABLE USES DISTINCT LETTERS, FLIPPER DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS, EXECUTABLE DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS, UNPROFITABLE USES DISTINCT LETTERS, QUESTIONABLE DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS, WINDOW DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS, TAMBOURINE USES DISTINCT LETTERS]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the character position to determine if it exists somewhere else in the string.
Consider the solution below:

```
        while (df.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = df.nextLine();
            String array[] = line.split("");
            String ans = "USES DISTINCT LETTERS";

            for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                if(line.indexOf(array[k]) != line.lastIndexOf(array[k])){
                    ans = "DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS";
                    break;
                }

            }//FOR LOOP

            System.out.println(line + " " + ans);

        }//WHILE DF
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
{

  for (int m = k + 1; m < array.length; m++)
  {
      if (!array[k].equals(array[m])
      {
        ans = "USES DISTINCT LETTERS";
      }
      else
      {
        ans = "DOES NOT USE DISTINCT LETTERS";
        // Break out of the two loops once you know the characters are matching. 
        //Otherwise it loops again and the last match of character is what you get the ans.
      }

   }//FOR LOOP2

}//FOR LOOP
```